# Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект c# (Windows.Froms)

Tags: c#, ооп

В классе Polynom у меня есть такие поля и конструкторы:

```
        private string[] coff1, coff2;
        private int deg1, deg2;

        public Polynom(string[] coff1, string[] coff2)
        {
            this.coff1 = coff1;
            this.coff2 = coff2;
        }

        public Polynom(int deg1, int deg2)
        {
            this.deg1 = deg1;
            this.deg2 = deg2;
        }
```

coff1 и coff2 - строчные массивы, которые хранят коэффициенты многочленов.
deg1 и deg2 - степени многочленов.
Также в этом классе есть метод, который складывает многочлены и возвращает строку

```
public  string Sum(string [] coff1,string [] coff2,int deg1,int deg2){...}
```

Как мне уже в классе Form1 по нажатию клавиши на определенный элемент добавить в textBox строку ответа? В классе Form1 я объявляю такие же поля и пишу следующий метод:

```
string[] coff1, coff2;
int deg1, deg2;

 private void sum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   coff1 = firstM.Text.Split(',');
   coff2 = secondM.Text.Split(',');
   deg1 = Convert.ToInt32(firstD.Text);
   deg2 = Convert.ToInt32(secondD.Text);
   answer.Text=Polynom.Sum(coff1, coff2, deg1, deg2);
}
```

Компилятор показывает ошибку в строке с answer "требуется ссылка на объект"
Укажите пожалуйста на ошибки с точки зрения ООП, правильно ли я написал поля и конструкторы?

Comment: Polynom сделайте статик и не вижу метода вашего класса Sum. А вообще, не понятно зачем вам в классе Polynom нужны поля, раз вы сразу Sum() со всеми параметрами вызываете?

Comment: у меня нет класса Sum, это название метода в классе Polynom, поэтому и создаю в нем поля

Comment: я про метод вам и писал. если хотите так его использовать, то ваш класс должен быть статичным

Comment: Спасибо, объявил весь класс с полями и методами статическими и все заработало

Comment: `объявил весь класс с полями и методами статическими` это значит что вы выбросили остатки ООП из приложения, даже при условии, что у вас его особо и не было. `с точки зрения ООП, правильно ли я написал поля` теперь точно ответ "нет".

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot сейчас в последней строке метода sum_Click подчеркивается "Sum" с ошибкой "Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру coff1 из Polynom.Sum(string[], string[], int, int)". Вообще, у меня несколько методов в классе полином, которые принимают 4 поля. Может ли это вызывать проблему?

Comment: @moonsharm по идее не может, но вслепую я не могу понять, о чем речь. Я дал вообще без аргументов вам этот метод, чтобы использовать данные, уже расположенные в классе.

Comment: @aepot понял свою ошибку, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не жалейте букв, вставляйте код класса целиком. Чтобы не пришлось угадывать код.

> Укажите пожалуйста на ошибки с точки зрения ООП, правильно ли я написал поля и конструкторы?

Очень мало контекста, чтобы ответить точно парвильно, но очевидно, если для суммы нужны все 4 аргумента, то и конструктор должен принимать их все. А то у вас получается 2 конструктора, которые принмают данные только частично и ни одним из них вы не воспользовались.

Чтобы вызвать конструктор класса и получить его экземпляр, нужно использовать ключевое слово `new`.

Попробую достроить.

```cs
public class Polynom
{
    private string[] coff1, coff2;
    private int deg1, deg2;

    public Polynom(string[] coff1, string[] coff2, int deg1, int deg2)
    {
        this.coff1 = coff1;
        this.coff2 = coff2;
        this.deg1 = deg1;
        this.deg2 = deg2;
    }

    public string Sum()
    {
        string result = ...;
        //...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Никакой статики здесь не должно быть.

```cs
private void sum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] coff1 = firstM.Text.Split(',');
    string[] coff2 = secondM.Text.Split(',');
    int deg1 = Convert.ToInt32(firstD.Text);
    int deg2 = Convert.ToInt32(secondD.Text);
    Polynom polynom = new Polynom(coff1, coff2, deg1, deg2);
    answer.Text = polynom.Sum();
}
```